# How does JAWS treat ARIA roles?

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria, uiaccessibility

How does JAWS interpret ARIA roles we define in the html? Does it have any mapping with the keystrokes we enter?
For example if we are setting the role=checkbox, in this scenario does the JAWS keystroke X detect this role and read it out. 
If we do not specify the role , does JAWS interpret it differently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, when you set a role, the browser surfaces that object to JAWS so you can navigate to it with quick keys as if it's a real checkbox.  If you set role=button, then B will navigate to the object.  If you set role=checkbox, then X will navigate to the object.

You still have to implement the actual interaction keys so that spacebar will select the button or check/uncheck the checkbox.